# Touchpad properties won't change with xinput

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, configuration, synaptics

I am running ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Dell Inspiron 7657

**First confusion**
xinput returns the following at terminal:

[mutliple touchpads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkziU.png)

as you can see in the above image, there are two ID's assigned to the touchpad: 14 and 17

Here are the xinput list-props 14 and xinput list-props 17 outputs:
 [xinput list-props 14 / 17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzZtc.jpg)

When I disable the 17, I can continue using the touchpad. I can't use the touchpad when I disable the 14.

**Second confusion**
Then, I try alternating several properties with the following commands,

xinput set-prop 14 .....
xinput set-prop 17 .....

in order to reduce the sensitivity of the touchpad and set some additional properties for palm detection. However, touchpad is still way too sensitive even though I set the properties like the following:

Synaptics Finger (294): 50, 110, 255

**Third confusion**
Whatever I do, I can't make a configuration stick. It resets to the default properties some time in the future.

**Ultimate Goal**

I would like to prevent the touchpad to make cursor jump around, paste irrelevant text to irrelevant places etc.. The default property set is horrible..
Actually this is mainly happening because of the design of my laptop. The relative location of the touchpad and the keyboard makes it very hard to type without touching the touchpad.

Any suggestions and explanations regarding these?

Comment: When you run `xinput list-props 14` or `17` is synaptics used or libinput?

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't know the answer of your question but I have edited the original question and I put images of  the output of xinput list-props 14/17, so that it may help you understand?